# Cómo ocultar el boton en jsp o marcarlo si el usuario logeado lo pulsa

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Lo que quiero hacer exactamente es extraer de una lista de asistentes
(a la que le paso un usuario y un evento), el usuario que asiste a ese
evento al confirmar el relleno del formulario y al volver a la tabla
que no muestre el botón de asistir puesto que ya se ha inscrito a ese evento.

el jsp del botón:

```
<a href="formularioAsiste.jsp?id=${ev.idEvento}" class="btn btn-default"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">Asistir</span></a>
```

El servlet del formulario

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String strIdEvento = request.getParameter("evento");
    Usuario asis = (Usuario) request.getSession().getAttribute("usuario");

    GestionEventos gesEven = new GestionEventos();

    Evento ev = gesEven.getEventoPorId(Integer.parseInt(strIdEvento));

    String nombreEntidad = request.getParameter("nombreEntidad");
    String nombreCuenta = request.getParameter("nombreCuenta");
    String iban = request.getParameter("iban");
    String numeroCuenta = request.getParameter("numeroCuenta");
    Date fechaPago = new Date();

    GestionAsistentes gestionAsistentes = new GestionAsistentes();


    Asiste asistente = new Asiste(nombreEntidad, nombreCuenta, iban, numeroCuenta, fechaPago);
    //asistente.setEvento(ev);
    //asistente.setUsuario(asis);
    asistente.setPrimaryKey(new UsuarioEventoId(asis,ev));

    gestionAsistentes.addAsistente(asistente);

    request.setAttribute("asistentes", gestionAsistentes.list());       

    //request.getRequestDispatcher("tablaAsiste.jsp").forward(request, response);
    response.sendRedirect("TablaEventosServlet");
}
```

El servlet que redirige al jsp con la tabla y los botones:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) hrows ServletException, IOException {
    GestionEventos gestionEventos = new GestionEventos();
    Collection<Evento> listaEventos = gestionEventos.list();
    request.setAttribute("eventos", listaEventos);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("tabla.jsp").forward(request, response);
    //request.getRequestDispatcher("TablaEventosServlet").forward(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guarda en sesión los eventos a lo que asistirá el usuario cuando se registre en uno.

```
session.setAttribute('eventos', listaEventos);
```

En la vista compruebas si el evento actual está en la lista de eventos a los que el usuario asistirá. Si está allí, quiere decir que el usuario ya se registró y no muestras el botón:

```
<c:if test="${!sessionScoped.eventos.contains(evento)}">
   <a href="formularioAsiste.jsp?id=${ev.idEvento}" class="btn btn-default"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">Asistir</span></a>
</c:if>
```

Ten en cuenta que `Collection#contains` usa el método `equals` para comprobar si un objeto existe en una colección (compara los objetos). Por eso, debes de sobreescribir `equals` en tu clase `Evento`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null)                return false;
    if(!(o instanceof) Evento) return false;

    Evento other = (Evento) o;
    return this.eventoId == other.eventoId;
}
```

En esta versión de `equals` deducimos si un evento es el mismo por medio de los ID.

Si trabajas con base de datos es igual, `${sessionScoped.usuario.eventos.contains(evento)}`, ya que se supone hay una relación entre `Usuario` y `Evento` de N - M.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo que propones funciona puesto que ya no se ve el botón, el problema es que no puedo visualizarlo para asistir, ¿Dónde debería colocar el `session.setAttribute("eventos", listaEventos);`? ¿en el servlet de mostrar la tabla con los datos o en el post de registro de asistente?

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta ya que olvidé negar la condición. La condición debería ser: `${!sessionScoped.eventos.contains(evento)}`. Si el usuario **NO** tiene ese evento, se muestra el botón. Prueba ahora y debería funcionar.

Comment: Pues si que se resiste el botón, ahora se visualiza pero todo el rato...

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Eso pasa porque no tienes implementado el método `equals` en la clase `Evento`.

Comment: **Nota:** he puesto eventoId, pero debes cambiarlo por como se llame la propiedad id de tu clase Evento.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes unos buenos conocimientos de programación, probaré a ver