# Problema con edición de formulario jsp

Tags: java, jsp, aplicación-web, servlets

> Tengo problemas para editar los campos en jsp, el planteamiento es el
>   siguiente: una tabla en la que se visualizan eventos y cada evento
>   dispone de un botón de asistir al mismo, el problema viene cuando
>   vuelvo a pulsar el botón para asistir, que debería llevarme de nuevo
>   al formulario pero esta vez de edición y no de nuevo registro.
>
> El jsp del formulario:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST"
        action="${(empty param.op) ? 'RegistroAsistenteServlet' : 'EditarAsistente'} ">
        <fieldset>


            <c:if test="${not empty param.id}">
                <input id="idevento" name="evento" type="hidden" value="${param.id}"/>
            </c:if>


            <c:if test="${not empty param.op }">
                <input id="textinput" name="id" type="hidden"
                    value="${asistentes.usuario }" />
            </c:if>

            <!-- Form Name -->
            <c:if test="${not empty param.op }">
                <legend>Modificar pago</legend>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${ empty param.op }">
                <legend>Formulario de pago</legend>
            </c:if>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Entidad</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input value="${asistentes.nombreEntidad }" id="textinput"
                        name="nombreEntidad" type="text" placeholder="ej: la Caixa"
                        class="form-control input-md" required="">

                </div>
            </div>
```

> El servlet de registro:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String strIdEvento = request.getParameter("evento");
        Usuario asis = (Usuario) request.getSession().getAttribute("usuario");

        GestionEventos gesEven = new GestionEventos();

        Evento ev = gesEven.getEventoPorId(Integer.parseInt(strIdEvento));

        String nombreEntidad = request.getParameter("nombreEntidad");
        String nombreCuenta = request.getParameter("nombreCuenta");
        String iban = request.getParameter("iban");
        String numeroCuenta = request.getParameter("numeroCuenta");
        Date fechaPago = new Date();

        GestionAsistentes gestionAsistentes = new GestionAsistentes();

        Asiste asistente = new Asiste(nombreEntidad, nombreCuenta, iban, numeroCuenta, fechaPago);

        asistente.setPrimaryKey(new UsuarioEventoId(asis,ev));

        gestionAsistentes.addAsistente(asistente);



        request.setAttribute("asistentes", gestionAsistentes.list());       


        response.sendRedirect("TablaEventosServlet");
    }
```

> El servlet de edición:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        String nombreEntidad = request.getParameter("nombreEntidad");
        String nombreCuenta = request.getParameter("nombreCuenta");
        String iban = request.getParameter("iban");
        String numeroCuenta = request.getParameter("numeroCuenta");
        Date fechaPago = new Date();

        GestionAsistentes gestionAsistentes = new GestionAsistentes();

        Asiste as = gestionAsistentes.getAsistentePorId(id);

        as.setNombreEntidad(nombreEntidad);
        as.setNombreCuenta(nombreCuenta);
        as.setIban(iban);
        as.setNumeroCuenta(numeroCuenta);
        as.setFechaPago(fechaPago);

        gestionAsistentes.editarAsistente(as);

        /*
         * Redireccionamos a la tabla de eventos
         */
        response.sendRedirect("TablaEventosServlet");
    }
```

> El servlet de la tabla donde se muestran los eventos:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        GestionEventos gestionEventos = new GestionEventos();

        Collection<Evento> listaEventos = gestionEventos.list();


        request.setAttribute("eventos", listaEventos);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("tabla.jsp").forward(request, response);




    }
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Tu [otro tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14027/c%C3%B3mo-ocultar-el-boton-en-jsp-o-marcarlo-si-el-usuario-logeado-lo-pulsa) se solucionó? Si es así, coloca tu solución o elije una respuesta.

La lógica que me imagino es muy simple:

**Evento**

```
public class Evento implements Serializable {

    private int idEvento;
    // otras propiedades

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(o == null) return false;
        if(!(o instanceof Evento)) return false;
        Evento o = (Evento) other;
        return this.idEvento == o.idEvento;
    }
}
```

**Login**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    List<Evento> usuarioEventos = /* consulta a bd por los eventos del usuario */
    session.setAttribute("usuarioEventos", usuarioEventos);
    // redirige hacia los eventos
    response.sendRedirect("/eventos");
}
```

**Registro**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // obtienes los parámetros y registras
    List<Evento> eventosUsuario = (List<Evento>) session.get("eventosUsuario");
    eventosUsuario.add(evento);
    // redirecciona al servlet "/eventos" que devuelve tabla.jsp
    response.sendRedirect("/eventos");
}
```

**Tabla de eventos**

```
<c:if test="${sessionScoped.eventosUsuario.contains(evento)}>
    <a href="/editarAsistencia?id=${evento.idEvento}">Editar asistencia</a>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!sessionScoped.eventosUsuario.contains(evento)}>
    <a href="/registrarAsistencia?id=${evento.idEvento}">Registrar asistencia</a>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo, como no quería saltarme las normas del foro he creado una duda a parte, tengo dos versiones de la misma aplicación, tan pronto lo pruebe marcare la respuesta y te respondo

Comment: Lo he estado probando y parece ser que funciona, coge los id y todo pero la pantalla se queda en blanco, parece que lo de editar no es lo mio

Comment: ¿La pantalla se queda en blanco? ¿podrías ser más específico?

Comment: creo que es porque redirecciono a un servlet, pero lo he intentado con un jsp y tampoco me deja, mañana seguiré probando a ver, tengo la sensación de que me dejo algo o paso algún parámetro vacío por alguna parte